# Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, .net, http-status-code-404, orchardcms

I uploaded my orchard web-site on a hosting. In "wwwroot" I created a new folder "slider" and uploaded jpg files into it. 
When I try to access them with the url "example.com/slider/1.jpg" I keep getting `Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.`
The file is there. I can see it on ftp. 
I tried doing the same thing on localhost and it gives me the same error.

I tried opening an image from a "Themes" folder. I've found a file "Theme.png" and I was able to open it in a browser. I added "1.jpg" to the same folder where I've found Theme.png and I wasn't able to open 1.jpg it gave me the same error message.

That's my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <remove name="host" />
      <remove name="pages" />
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.Razor.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
        <add namespace="Orchard.Mvc.Html"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Slide or Slider?  You say you created a folder called slider but are trying to access with /slide/...

Comment: it's slider. the problem isn't in mistyping

Comment: Is this locally hosted or on a server? Did you configure IIS bare or is it shared hosting from a typical hosting provider?

Comment: You're probably missing a web.config in the folder where the files are.

Comment: no i'm not. I've just added it to my message above.

Comment: I think the resource in the error is not related to a image/part resource. I believe this is a DLL assembly reference error.
I would check that all referenced assemblies are copied to the server, and that you have the desired privileges to the server.

I would also implement some sort of logging in the web application and copy the PDB files with the DLL files in the "/bin" folder. That way, you can handle the exception in the Application_Error in your Global.asax file and log the Exception, the InnerException (if any) and the StackTrace.

Answer (score 2):

Have you added a web.config file to the slider folder as described in this [answer about a 404 with a JavaScript file](/a/9721841/31569).

Comment: I created the web.config file in slider folder and everything works right now. Thank you again!